# can php code break down shared hosting services for the particular IP?

Tags: php, shared-hosting

Sorry, i had to put the same post again due to still no solution

I have a strange problem, i just installed my php web site on a shared hosting(php,apache,mysql,linux), all services were working fine. But after configuring my app i just could visit my web site only once, other attempts gives "The server is taking too long to respond.". But from other IP i can access, but only once, it seems all ip addresses being blocked after first visit(even ftp and other services go down, no access at all from the IP), can anyone help to explore this problem ? i don't think that it's my app problem, the app works fine on my local PC. By far The only one is there might be a infinity loop in my code becouse i had this issues on my local pc, but i fixed it, should work fine everywhere. Can infinity loop make blocking all services bind(if this is the way) to particular IP ? but im not sure about this. Never thought this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at an infinite loop issue more.  I had a similar issue that only showed up on  the shared server because my local machine had a different version of php and different error settings.

Comment: php infinite loop can be reason for blocking all services(ftp, ssh ..) for IPs ?  how that possible ? can you share on this more ? thanks!

Comment: i'm not completely sure but to my understanding it crashes the server.       I'm not sure how this works with shared hosting or what a host would do to avoid this issue.  I expect shutting down your site for an amount of time would be their answer to protect other users of that server.

Comment: try using the same versions of php and apache that your host uses for testing.  i use wampserver to make switching easy.  check you php.ini and httpd.comf. your host may or may not have these available. then if no problems show up on your local server i would delete and upload everything anew.

Comment: problem solved, it was php a code issue, after few hours review i found out where is the hell in my code, so my system uses multiple mysql(version 4.1) connections and it tried to connect to the same db with same credentals, this causes a problem with mysql 4.1 versions( minor bag).

Comment: So now everything works fine, WalterJ89 and other guys who tried to help me, thank you all too much for your afford :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem either with sessions or database connections. Is there a page's code that you could share that causes this problem?

Comment: i afraid the code is too big to share, im checking now the session and db parts. thanks anyways!